# export excel 2010 file with iXBRL tags using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, xbrl

This is my first post; I've taught myself how to write VBA code from this site (thanks :))and others but never posted....

Im trying to produce a set of financial statements and I'd like to export it direct to HMRC using iXBRL tags

I've done some research around the problem but most of the stuff I find is not really relevant to excel (eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBRL#iXBRL)

Is there any way, after organising data into the relevant format on the sheet, to tag the values of cells (or VBA variables) with iXBRL tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd honestly suggest buying some commercial software that allows the tagging of Excel files for iXBRL.  This isn't something you're going to easily solve with VBA, it's a very complex problem.

Once you convert to XHTML, each fact in your accounts will require an XML tag that identifies the concept, period, and multiple dimensions (which are in groups of hypercubes and each concept can have different hypercubes).

That's before you get onto currency, scaling, decimals and iXBRL format transformations and the various HMRC validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do anything with the iXBRL or MHTML, as its already done, your just changing the figures.

First you need to prepare the template.

1. Download any set of accounts that is already in the iXBRL format.
2. Parse the file to get the variables that need to be changed, and replace them with Tags of your own.

Then this template can be used over and over again, just by parsing the file and replacing the tags with the figures from the bs and p&l.

Its a couple of hours to prepare the template.

No need to do anything with the iXBRL or MHTML, as its already done, your just changing the figures.